# How to make viewFlipper like this

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I've a `viewFlipper` that I'm using for a `slideShow`.

I saw this is an application that I liked:

[image]

As you can see, there is a narrow channel under it that indicate in which image we are and it becomes larger and smaller with the amount of childrens in `viewflipper`.

It's really interesting but I don't know how can I make one.

Could you help me ?

Comment: look into [this](http://asishinwp.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/android-viewflipper-with-page-indicator/)

Comment: Try this Github project [https://github.com/kevintanhongann/Android-ViewFlipperIndicator](https://github.com/kevintanhongann/Android-ViewFlipperIndicator)